# Which branch of combinatorics solves this problem?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I have a 1024 × 1024 sudoku puzzle.To solve this puzzle it would take enormous amount of time even for a powerful desktop computer.

There are huge number of different ways to write numbers on 1024 × 1024 sudoku grid, but only one of them is correct.

Combinatorics gives us number of ways that one can write numbers on a 1024 × 1024 sudoku grid,but it doesn't tell how to solve it in few steps.

I am trying to come up with a technique to solve this 1024 × 1024 sudoku puzzle in few number of steps.

So which branch of combinatorics should I study to solve this problem?

Comment: "but only one of them is correct," i.e. you already have some spaces filled in ahead of time?  The sudoku problem is essentially that of the [graph-coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring) problem, where vertices correspond to entries in the grid, and edges exist between vertices if they are on the same row, in the same subgrid, or in the same column, and colors correspond to the numbers in the grid.  As far as I remember, it is an NP-Complete problem to decide if a graph is colorable with a specific number of colors, and that should include the case if some colors predetermined

Answer (score 1):

The wikipedia page on the mathematics of Sudoku states that "The general problem of solving Sudoku puzzles on $n^2 \times n^2$ boards of $n \times n$ blocks is known to be NP-complete". The upshot of this is that unless P=NP (very unlikely), there is no efficient algorithm to solve Sudoku puzzles in general.